# Vue.js - How to remove an array element upon selection by <select> tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

i want  to remove elements from this array when they get selected but v-on:change is not the right option because when you select an item, the select value will change twice so the method will also get executed twice (two elements will be removed)  i thought of making a new directive to do this job ,but i want to leave it as my last option ...thank you

```js
new Vue({
el:"#app",
data :{
    arr:['1','2','3','4'],
     selected:""
  },
methods :{
splice (){
 this.arr.splice(this.arr.indexOf(this.selected),1)
     }
   }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
<select v-model="selected" @change="splice">
<option v-for="item in arr" >{{ item }}</option>
</select>
<div>
```

this was my attempt, but like i said it get executed twice because select value changes twice and also i want to do more stuff on item selection so maybe i should just make a directive

Comment: Your logic is not very clear. If all selected will be removed, what should be your selected state?

Comment: well , basically what i want  is that when i select an item i want that exact item to be removed of my array

Comment: on that case my selected stat should be blank

Comment: What I am guessing is that you don't need a select box as it doesn't seem to be a good fit here. Maybe a simple list which fires an event to remove the element when clicked?

Comment: Initially your `selected` is empty and when you use `indexOf` that will returns -1 you're removing the last selected one

Comment: i tried to add a disabled option but still the same

Comment: @Psidom yeah that could be a solution but i don't really want to display a whole list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a default option with a null value to fallback to, it will work by first re-assigning `this.selected = null` and then splicing the options array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      arr: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
      selected: null
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeElement(e) {
      this.selected = null
      this.arr.splice(this.arr.indexOf(e.target.value), 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected" @change="removeElement">
    <option :value="null" disabled>-- Select --</option>
    <option v-for="item in arr">{{ item }}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using a simple list to achieve what you needed, which seems to be a better fit for your case;

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    arr: ['1','2','3','4'],
    removed: ""
  },
  methods: {
    splice (item, index) {
      this.removed = item
      this.arr.splice(index, 1)
    }
  }
})
```

```css
ul {
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 55px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 0px;
}

li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="(item, index) in arr" @click="splice(item, index)">{{ item }}</li>
  </ul>
  Removed: {{ this.removed }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is using `watch` property to watch the `selected` item and remove it from the array:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    arr: ['1', '2', '3', '4'],
    selected: ""
  },
  methods: {

  },
  watch: {
    selected(v) {
      if (this.selected !== "") {
        this.arr.splice(this.arr.indexOf(v), 1)
      }
      this.selected=""
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <select v-model="selected">
    <option v-for="item in arr">{{ item }}</option>
  </select>
  <div>
```